# How to remove an element from a Mobx observable array, without causing the entire consuming component to rerender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

So let's say i have a todoStore. It has an action that deletes a todo by id. Note that i tried both filter and splice:

```
export default class TodosStore {
    constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)  
    }

    todos = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "name1",
            completed: true
        },
        {
            id: 15,
            name: "name2",
            completed: true
        },
        {
            id: 14,
            name: "name3",
            completed: true
        }
    ]

    removeTodo(id) {
        // this.todos = this.todos.filter(todo=>todo.id != id)

        for (let todo of this.todos) {
            if (todo.id == id) {
                const indexOf = this.todos.indexOf(todo)
                this.todos.splice(indexOf, 1)
            }
        }
    }    
};
```

The consuming Todos component(Note that i'm wrapping the Todo with observer):

```
import { combinedStores } from "."    
const ObservableTodo = observer(Todo);

export default observer(() => {
    const { todosStore } = combinedStores       

    return (
        <div >
          {todosStore.todos.map(todo=>{
              return(
                <ObservableTodo onDelete={()=>{todosStore.removeTodo(todo.id)}} onNameChange={(value)=>{todosStore.editTodoName(todo.id,value)}} key={todo.id} todo={todo}></ObservableTodo>
               )
            })}
        </div>
    )
})
```

The simple Todo component:

```
export default ({todo,onNameChange,onDelete}) => {
    return (
        <div style={{padding:'10px',margin:'10px'}}>
            <p>ID: {todo.id}</p>
            <input onChange={(e)=>{onNameChange(e.target.value)}}  value={todo.name}></input>
            <p>Completed: {todo.completed ? 'true' : 'false'} <button onClick={onDelete} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></p>            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Even though i'm clearly **mutating**(as opposed to constructing a new array) the todos array within the store, Todos component rerenders(i see it via console.logs),
and so does every remaining Todo component.

Is there any way around it? Is there anything wrong with my setup perhaps? I'm using latest Mobx(6) and mobx-react.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Todos` component is supposed to rerender because it depends on `todos` array content (because it `map`'s over it). So when you change `todos` content by adding or removing some todo - `Todos` component will rerender because it needs to render new content, new list of todos.

Each single `Todo` rerenders because you have not wrapped it with `observer`. It is a good practice to wrap every component which uses some observable state, and `Todo` is clearly the one that does.

Comment: I did wrap the Todo with an observer. I just do it outside of the component(where i import the Todo, in Todos).

Comment: Good! Like @Ivan said you also need to somehow get rid of creating new functions every render. `useCallback` hook is a good start, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You change the `length` of the `todo` array, so the `map` function kicks in. Then while you are iterating over the elements, you are passing `new` properties to the `ObservableTodo` component (`onDelete`, `onChange`) this will make the `ObservableTodo` always rerender.

Even though the component is a Mobx observable, it still follows the "React rules", and when react sees `new` references in component properties, it will render the component.